# MYSQL LIKE Wildcards exclude NULL values

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause, wildcard

In my dog db I'm trying to select on multiple values.

I have a column "dna" which can be eithe DNA DNAComp or NULL

If I select with a wildcard ie

```
WHERE dna LIKE "%";
```

I was hoping to get all dogs but I get only dogs where dna is not NULL.

I also tried :

WHERE `dna` IN ('DNA','DNAComp',NULL);

with similar results (ie null records are ignored).

Any ideas?

Gary

Comment: You don't need a WHERE if you want to select all dogs , because if you want all dogs a `SELECT * FROM dog` or something like that would be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use

```
WHERE dna IN ('DNA','DNAComp' ) or dna is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `IFNULL`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE IFNULL(dna, '') LIKE '%'
```